# What's the minimum revenue an LLC must make in Florida or NY states?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, income-tax

Here in Italy, if you open a small company (sort of LLC) you must have a minimum revenue, and therefore you must pay a minimum amount of taxes every year. Too bad for you if you are not making money; you must pay anyway.

The basic idea behind this Italian approach is to avoid people opening fake LLC to deduct tons of costs and create huge VAT credit without ever making some revenues.

Is there something similar in U.S. for LLC? Does a U.S. LLC have to make at least a certain amount of revenue? Or pay at least a certain amount of taxes every year?

What happens if they don't make revenue for one year; does the IRS come to visit/audit?

---

**EDIT:** LLC in Florida. Anyway I was more interested in the average situation in US states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the State. In California, for example, you pay a franchise tax of $800 every year just for having LLC, and in addition to that - income tax on gross revenue. But in other States (like Wyoming, for example) there's no taxes at all, only registration fees (which may still amount to ~$100-300 a year).

IRS doesn't care about LLC's at all (unless you chose to treat is as a corporation).

You need to understand that in the US we have the "Federal Government" (IRS is part of that) and the "State Government" that deals with business entities, in each of the 50 States.

Since you're talking about Italy, and not EU, you should similarly be talking about the relevant State, and not US.

Comment: Florida! But are people in US planning to split back the country into 50 separate states like what people want to do here in Europe?! :-)

Comment: @MarcoDemaio some would like to. Especially here, in California, where we carry the majority of the Republican red-neck electorate from out of state on our backs... The point is that other than the foreign/monetary/military/immigration policy, the US states are pretty sovereign.

Comment: Think of the U.S. as an Umbrella corp for each State =D